# Dynamic link to the MinGW runtime

Tags: gcc, runtime, mingw

I read somewhere that MinGW statically links the c/c++ runtime. How can I dynamically  link them to reduce the executable size? I don't need to worry about the dependency issue, as the final program will run on a Linux box. I am just doing a proof-of-concept prototype on windows, and need to show that the produced executable is very small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link with -shared-libgcc, as usual. However, beware that the standard Debian mingw is built without shared libgcc support (though we have a version in our repository where I enabled that).

Comment: I am using mingw on windows, as I mentioned in the question.